# Conditional Formulas in Excel 2013

Tags: excel, vba

Good day folks! Can you please help me with the following excel problem (Please see below)

```
                        July    Aug     Sep     Oct    Nov    Dec
Total Assets (USD'K)    32      36       38     31
```

Current Month : (Drop-Down list for all months)

Monthly Change in Total Assets  = Current Month - Previous Month

So, here is the situation:

1. Each month I need to new add statistics to my worksheet. For example, when new data for Total Assets in November arrives, I need to insert it above under the heading "Nov", etc.
2. After inserting new data, I need to select from the drop-down list current month (for example, "Nov").
3. Afterwards, "Monthly Change in Total Assets" needs to be calculated automatically. For instance, "Total Assets in November - Total Assets in October".

I assume that, I need to use conditional calculation functions. But it did not work the way I expected.

Can you please help, me. Thank you in advance for your kind assistance.

Sincerely,

Comment: `did not work the way I expected` is a totally useless description of any kind of a problem. it gives no information for problem solving whatsoever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the layout of the data is similar to as shown in the image, try this...

In B5

```
=IF(COUNT(B2:G2)=0,"",IF(COUNT(B2:G2)=1,B2,INDEX(B2:G2,MATCH(B4,B1:G1,0))-INDEX(B2:G2,MATCH(B4,B1:G1,0)-1)))
```

[image]

Comment: @MRMODELLING You're welcome! Glad it worked. Please take a minute to accept the answer to mark your question as Solved. :)